# Divide a video into multiple child videos using Python

Tags: python, automation

I do create screen recording videos, then use a video editing software to divide the (screen-record.mp4) to three different videos.

ex: (screen-record.mp4 => blue-area1.mp4 & blue-area2.mp4 & blue-area3.mp4).

[image: original video template]

However, it does take a lot of effort & time to be done manually,

Is there a way to automate this process using python or something, i'm new to python.

Comment: You can use `ffmpeg` with python. See https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop video with `cv2` lib:

```
import cv2


def crop_video(file, coordinates, output):
    """ Crop video """
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    fps, frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    x, y, w, h = coordinates
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, fps, (w, h))
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            crop_frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            out.write(crop_frame)
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, coord in enumerate([(0, 0, 960, 540), (960, 0, 959, 539), (960, 540, 959, 539)]):
        crop_video('video.mp4', coord, f'output{i+1}.mp4')
```

Input sample:

[image: input]

Output samples:

[image: output1]

[image: output2]

[image: output3]